# box2d + C# (Visual Studio 2008 or less). Need an example of code

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, box2d

All the examples I have ever seen are for visual studio 2010. Help me to find a simple older example please. And without of xna (if it is possible).

Comment: What is this "Box2D" you speak of? There is no such thing in the .NET BCL.

Comment: http://code.google.com/p/box2dx/

it is an old port of box2d which is crossplatform

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't found any code for old VS so I installed Visual Studio 2010 with the latest version of XNA.